# Can I integrate samsung "All Share" with my android application on samsung phones

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I want to integrate samsung "All Share" functionality with my android app in the same way we integrate Twitter and Facebook api to share photos and videos. Is it possible.

I've a photosharing application like instagram, on which user can upload images and videos. The instagram enables to share those pictures on facebook and twitter. I've similar functionality, but now I even want to integrate the "all share" feature of samsung into samsung phones, with which i'll be able to view the images and videos on samsung TV and other samsung devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can. Samsung provides the 'AllShare Framework SDK' for Android devices: http://developer.samsung.com/allshare-framework

Comment: How to get this tool , it asks to install eclipse and use their plugin for eclipse.. how can I get this framework for android studio?

Comment: I'm afraid it's now available as a plugin for Eclipse. The best for you is to contact Samsung support at developer.samsung.com

Answer (score 0):

yes u can easily merge an all share application with any android application but make sure ur eclipse has the all share plugin ....if dont then u can go to their official website and can download it
http://developer.samsung.com/allshare-framework/start
here u will find all the steps to download the allshare plugin